# Remove sorting from Datatable in checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Whenever I click on select-all on top of the table it goes back to the first page. I need to select some rows in the table and export them to a CSV file but when selecting on different pages, when I click on select all it goes back to page 1.

```html
<td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_<?php echo $valuep['0'] ;?>">
      <input id="checkbox_<?php echo $valuep['0'] ;?>" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="<?php echo $valuep['0'] ;?>" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" id="enable_all" name="enable_all" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="lead_contact_id_<?php echo $valuep['0'] ;?>" name="contact_id" value="<?php echo $valuep['0'] ;?>">
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
```

```js
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  'columnDefs': [{
    'targets': 0,
    'searchable': false,
    'orderable': false,
    'className': 'checkbox check-success'
  }],
  'order': [
    [1, 'asc']
  ]
});
```

Comment: Where is the 'select all' logic? Are you loading the content dynamically thought AJAX?

Comment: The data is using normal sql query in php

Comment: The select all logic is given by default there is no implementation just (#mytable).Datatable();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suggest try trigger click all checkbox in the current visible page.

```js
var myTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  'columnDefs': [{
    'targets': 0,
    'searchable': false,
    'orderable': false,
  }],
  'order': [
    [1, 'asc']
  ],
});


$(document).on('click', '#select_all', function() {
        $('input.select_click', document).each(function() {
        $(this).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
<thead>
  <th><a href="#" id="select_all">Select All</a></th>
  <th>Data</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_1" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="1" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 1</td>
  
</tr>


<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>



<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>



<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>



<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>




<tr>
  
  <td class="check_box_data">
  <div class="checkbox check-success">
    <label class=" mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline" for="checkbox_1">
      <input id="checkbox_2" type="checkbox" name="leads_ids" value="2" class="select_click">
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <span id="custom_controls"></span>
</td>
<td>Test Data 2</td>
  
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```